# Tricky intersection in Relational Algebra

Tags: intersection, relational-algebra

Hi there for my exam revision i had picked up the following sample question for relational algebra:

```
employee (+person_name, street, city)
works (+person_name, company_name, salary)
company (+company_name, city)
manages (+person_name, manager_name)

+ indicate the underlined primary keys
```

1. Find the names of all employees who live in the same city and on the same street as their managers

   ```
         MY solution
   JOIN manages and employee (OVER person_name) GIVING T1
   JOIN manages and employee (OVER manager_name) GIVING T2
   PROJECT T1 over person_name, street, city GIVING T3
   PROJECT T2 over street, city GIVING T4
   T3 intersect T4 GIVING T5
   PROJECT T5 over person_name GIVING RESULT
   ```

This was my solution until I had found out about that the intersection has to be union-compatible (number of columns matching and their headings)

Since then I couldn’t really find a solution to this problem because if I do the following change to line-3
PROJECT T1 over street, city GIVING T3
then I will never have the opportunity to link the result of intersection back to person_name.

On the other hand when I would make the following change to line-4: 
PROJECT T2 over person_name, street, city GIVING T4
Then upon the intersection I would never get a person who has any other manager than himself.

I would appreciate any hints given, perhaps this online sample i picked up is quite ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to phrase the question: for every manager+person pair, find those for which the related city+state are the same for both people.  You almost did that:

```
JOIN manages AND employee (OVER person_name) GIVING T1
JOIN T1 AND employee (OVER manager_name, street, city) GIVING T2
PROJECT T2 OVER person_name, manager_name, street, city GIVING RESULT
```

The problem statement does not require the names to returned in a single column, and this answer provides a useful result.  If need be, you could repeat the above query, taking the union of two projections: one of person_name and the other of manager_name.

Just one thing: many managers would object to one column named "person" and the other "manager" because almost every manager -- your experience notwithstanding, perhaps? -- considers himself a person.  More acceptable pairs might be manager/worker, lord/serf, master/slave, etc.